# gdb is jumping over lines

Tags: c++, gdb

i have some problems on understanding gdb.

i have a main function, i wrote this main function on myself.

Some lines in this main, call some functions in a library, i think library name is not important but it is tesseract-ocr.

my line in main which call a function, a constructor is here:

```
choiceItr = new tesseract::ChoiceIterator(itr);
```

i put a break point at gdb on above line, and run, when it stops on that line i use step command to go into the function.

Here is the library function who is called:

```
ChoiceIterator::ChoiceIterator(const ResultIterator& result_it) {
  ASSERT_HOST(result_it.it_->word() != NULL);
  tesseract_ = result_it.tesseract_;
  PAGE_RES_IT res_it(*result_it.it_);
  WERD_CHOICE* best_choice = res_it.word()->best_choice;
  BLOB_CHOICE_LIST_CLIST* choices = best_choice->blob_choices();
  if (choices != NULL) {
    BLOB_CHOICE_LIST_C_IT blob_choices_it(choices);
    for (int blob = 0; blob < result_it.blob_index_; ++blob)
      blob_choices_it.forward();
    choice_it_ = new BLOB_CHOICE_IT(blob_choices_it.data());
    choice_it_->mark_cycle_pt();
  } else {
    choice_it_ = NULL;
  }
}
```

then i use "next" command of gdb to walk in function.

here is my gdb console:

```
Breakpoint 1, pixsOfOneWord (langString=0x8049e7c "klm", 
    imageString=0x8049e71 "paket2.tif", outputData=0x8049c7b, 
    datapathString=0x8049e6f ".") at deneme234.cpp:161
161 choiceItr = new tesseract::ChoiceIterator(itr);
(gdb) step
tesseract::ChoiceIterator::ChoiceIterator (this=0x819e6f0, result_it=...)
    at resultiterator.cpp:234
234     choice_it_ = new BLOB_CHOICE_IT(blob_choices_it.data());
(gdb) next
225   ASSERT_HOST(result_it.it_->word() != NULL);
(gdb) list
220     return it_->word()->box_word->BlobPosition(blob_index_) == SP_DROPCAP;
221   return false;
222 }
223 
224 ChoiceIterator::ChoiceIterator(const ResultIterator& result_it) {
225   ASSERT_HOST(result_it.it_->word() != NULL);
226   tesseract_ = result_it.tesseract_;
227   PAGE_RES_IT res_it(*result_it.it_);
228   WERD_CHOICE* best_choice = res_it.word()->best_choice;
229   BLOB_CHOICE_LIST_CLIST* choices = best_choice->blob_choices();
(gdb) next
278 }  // namespace tesseract.
(gdb) next
226   tesseract_ = result_it.tesseract_;
(gdb) next
278 }  // namespace tesseract.
(gdb) next
226   tesseract_ = result_it.tesseract_;
(gdb) next
230   if (choices != NULL) {
(gdb)
```

as you can see,

```
tesseract_ = result_it.tesseract_;
```

line has been called two times, why?

```
PAGE_RES_IT res_it(*result_it.it_);
WERD_CHOICE* best_choice = res_it.word()->best_choice;
BLOB_CHOICE_LIST_CLIST* choices = best_choice->blob_choices();
```

also when i "next", above lines was not called, why?

Thanks in advnce.

Comment: Are you compiling with debug options and without optimization?

Comment: @VJo, Thanks for the reply, i must confess i did not compile library's(tesseract) source code, i am using a precompiled package. When i see that i can step into tesseract function, i think it is ok with compilation. I am compiling my own source that contains main with only "-g". I am going to search to compile main without optimization. But can you say, should i compile tesseract without optimization and debug options? If so with which debug options, do you mean "-g"?  Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are using g++, then pass `-g -O0` to get not optimized code with debug symbols

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The library you are stepping into has been built with optimization and debug symbols (most likely `-g -O2`, which is the default for Linux builds).

Debugging optimized code is somewhat hard, as control flow optimization causes the code to "jump around", some variables become "`<optimized out>`", etc.

You can rebuild the library with `CXXFLAGS = -g -O0`, or you can learn to debug with optimization on.

The latter is a very useful skill, as many times your program will *only* crash in optimized mode, and you'll have to debug it in that mode anyway.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, i changed the Makefile in the root of code dir of library, with O2 to O0, make uninstall old one. After that runautoconf, configure, make, make install again. But still gdb runs as above transcript.

Comment: "I changed the Makefile in the root of code dir of library". What makes you believe that is sufficient?  Rebuild it again, logging all commands the build executes, and verify that `resultiterator.cpp` was in fact built with `-O0` and not `-O2`. If it *is* built with `-O0`, then you are not using the library you've just built.

Comment: Thanks, @Employed Russian. I export CFLAGS=-g -O0 CXXFLAGS=-g -O0 and runautoconf, configure, make clean, make install. And now gdb runs all the code line by line in order, now i have other questions about specifically tesseract, maybe in another question. thanks.

Comment: Yes this is a problem with g++ and not with gdb/ddd. Not only does it make gdb skip lines, it also produces wrong output because it sometimes optimizes stuff wrongly. I faced the problem with c++11 with gcc-5.4.0, for an assignment which was the last line in a constructor - that line was simply getting skipped when -O3 was used, but making it -O0 made the code work correctly.

Comment: @R71 While compiler bugs (producing wrong code) are not unheard of, it is *extremely* unlikely that you've discovered one in a released version of GCC. More likely your code has undefined behavior, which allows compiler to do *anything* it wants (including skipping parts of your code entirely).

Comment: @employedrussian, how do we verify that file is compiled using which flags? Means using created object file, can we know this?

Comment: thanks Employed Russian for this answer. in my question that you marked as duplicate mariadb is compiled with -O2 optimizations.