# gdb `list` command only shows one line number instead of contents when attaching to a process

Tags: c++, c, gdb

I invoked gdb to attach a current running process with this command `sudo gdb binary PID`. After that I set breakpoints and typed `continue` in gdb. Then I sent a request to this process to hit the breakpoint. After that, when I type command `list`, it only shows one line instead of multiple lines as expected, and it only shows line number instead of contents. And may I ask what does the output of command `n` mean? On the internet some docs mentioned it means the next line to be executed. But from the output itself, it doesn't make too much sense to me(after two `n` commands the last `l` command shows 169 instead of 172 or 174). Can anyone help answer above two questions? Really appreciate it.

```
(gdb) l
164 in CBFEMultiSectionResponseModule.cc
(gdb) n
172 in CBFEMultiSectionResponseModule.cc
(gdb) l
167 in CBFEMultiSectionResponseModule.cc
(gdb) n
174 in CBFEMultiSectionResponseModule.cc
(gdb) l
169 in CBFEMultiSectionResponseModule.cc
```

The build command line for this source file is like this:

```
/usr/bin/g++ -c -fPIC -DMODULEADAPTER_BUILTIN_VERSION=\"2.36.375.10894.aff30c2\" -DLINUX -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_THREAD_SAFE -DUSE_STD_YUTSTRING  -I../api -I. -I/home/y/include/ydisc \
-I/home/y/include/avro -I../.. -I../../.. -I../../../external_interfaces -I../../../sg_interfaces -I/home/y/include64 -I/home/y/include     
\-fPIC -g -O2 -Wall -Werror -Wno-invalid-offsetof -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -MD -MP   
\-DYAHOO_PLATFORM_MAJOR=6 -DYAHOO_PLATFORM_MINOR=10 CBFEMultiSectionResponseModule.cc -o x86_64-linux-gcc/CBFEMultiSectionResponseModule.o
```

This is the filesystem type:

```
-bash-4.1$ df -Th
Filesystem     Type   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1      ext4   246G   97G  137G  42% /
tmpfs          tmpfs   12G   30M   12G   1% /dev/shm
```

Below is the output of `info source`:

```
(gdb) info source
Current source file is CBFEMultiSectionResponseModule.cc
Compilation directory is /home/myusername/ufe/modules/multisectionresponse/impl
Source language is c++.
Compiled with DWARF 2 debugging format.
Does not include preprocessor macro info.
```

Below is the output of `shell cat`:

```
(gdb) shell cat /home/myusername/ufe/modules/multisectionresponse/impl/CBFEMultiSectionResponseModule.cc
cat: /home/myusername/ufe/modules/multisectionresponse/impl/CBFEMultiSectionResponseModule.cc: No such file or directory
```

Comment: That happens if you have not compiled with debugging info. Please show your build command line. If using `gcc` the option is `-g`.

Comment: As for the second part of the question we would need to see your actual code to be able to comment more. For example it could be in a loop, switch, if, or other jump code.

Comment: For the second part it could also be because the compiler has changed the order that some source code lines are executed. It can do that for optimisation or other reasons.

Comment: @kaylum, I've added the build command. It seems there is a `-g` option in it though. Sorry I can't share with you the code since it's our company's code.

Comment: That's only one intermediate step in the full build process. It's possible your final binary has been stripped. Run `file <your_binary>` to check. It should say `stripped` or `not stripped`.

Comment: It looks like this is you have debug info, but gdb can't find the source file.

Comment: @kaylum, it seems both the binary and the loaded .so file generated by the A.cc file has `not stripped` attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I type command list, it only shows one line instead of multiple lines as expected, and it only shows line number instead of contents

This is most likely happening because GDB has no access to the source. The `sudo` is the key here. Your source likely resides on a filesystem that doesn't allow root access, such as NFS.

> it doesn't make too much sense to me(after two n commands the last l command shows 169 instead of 172 or 174).

You are debugging optimized code. See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8067626/50617).

**Update:**

> The path to source is correct in the compilation environment. However, the runtime environment is different than the compilation env ..

Well, why didn't you tell us *that*?

My answer is correct: GDB doesn't list source because source is inaccessible (it's just inaccessible for a different reason from what I guessed).

If you want GDB `list` command to work in the runtime environment, then you *must* make the source available (though not necessarily in the same location; use `dir` command to point GDB to the location where sources are available).

**Update 2:**

> . I used to think GDB has some magic ways to get the source code from the binary.

The binary does not contain sources (that would make significantly larger). Instead, it contains *references* to the source locations.

In particular, the compiler encodes into the binary for each translation unit (each `.cpp` file):

1. Compilation directory
2. Name of the source file(s) (there could be more than one due to `#include`s).
3. A mapping from program counter to file/line that the particular chunk of assembly was generated for.

(There is additional info describing variable locations, types, etc. But these are irrelevant to the `list` command.)

GDB decodes above into, locates the source file(s), and allows you to set breakpoints by file/line, lists the source when you hit the breakpoint, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your insights. I've added the filesystem type in the question statement, would you please take a look at it? It that the reason caused the list command issue? And for the second question, you may be right, since the compiling command use -O2 and I do see some value get optimized out in GDB.

Comment: @HardMode Please edit your question and add output from `(gdb) info source`.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your reply. I have added the output of `info source` and `info sources`. Thanks

Comment: @HardMode You need to show `info source` at the point *where the problem happens*, i.e. when executing the `next` command. Also, does it *really* print `A.cc`? What is the *actual* output?

Comment: Hi, I have added the output of `info source` and modified the `A.cc` to reflect the actual output. Would you please take a look at it? Thanks.

Comment: @HardMode. We are getting closer. What happens when you do `(gdb) shell cat /home/myusername/ufe/modules/multisectionresponse/impl/CBFEMultiSectionResponseModule.cc` while the problem is happening?

Comment: Hi, I have added the output of  `(gdb) shell cat` to the question, would you please take a look at it? Thanks

Comment: @HardMode Ok, so the file isn't readable by `cat` either. Is the path to source  what you expect it to be? Can you access it with `cat` from outside of GDB? Is it _really_ on the local partition?

Comment: The path to source is correct in the compilation environment. However, the runtime environment is different than the compilation env and the runtime env doesn't have those source files, so in the runtime env the `cat` command within `gdb` or outside of `gdb` will both fail. At compilation env the `cat` command with that path to source file will both succeed inside `gdb` or outside of `gdb`.

Comment: Sorry I am kind of newbie to GDB and didn't realize this. I used to think GDB has some magic ways to get the source code from the binary... Yes, after I copied the source code to runtime env and used `dir` to specify the folder, `list` command can show 10 lines with contents now. Thank you very much.