# C++ - Method returns non-null pointer according to gdb but the variable it's assigned to is null

Tags: c++, pointers, null, gdb, remote-debugging

I have a problem where I call a method from a statically linked library and the method returns a pointer to a datastructure. According to the debugger the value that is returned is non-null. But after the method returns and the value is assigned to a local variable, the variable is null.

The screen recording below demonstrates the problem. The recording starts before the method is called, then steps into the method and back out. As you can see, the method returns a pointer to the address 0x6920ae10 but then the value stored in the local pointer variable is 0x0.

[image]

I'm at a loss here... I have been using C++ for many years but i never encountered a problem like that before.. Am I missing something stupid here? What could cause this problem?

I compiled the statically linked library (LLRP for Impinj RFID Readers) just before, directly on the machine where the code is executed and i also just recompiled the whole program on the same machine, so I don't think it's a mismatch between the binary code on the remote machine and the code in the IDE.

The same code did work before, but now it's running on a different platform (on a Raspberry Pi instead of an Alix-board and on Raspbian instead of Ubuntu).

**Update:**
I have been investigating this problem further today and i found that the problem occurs here (slightly changed to the code in the animation but the problem is the same):

```cpp
::LLRP::CReaderEventNotificationData *p_msg_ren_d = ((::LLRP::CREADER_EVENT_NOTIFICATION *) p_msg)->getReaderEventNotificationData();

if (p_msg_ren_d == NULL)
{
    delete p_connection;
    delete p_msg;
    this->_fail("Invalid response from reader (1).");
     return;
}
```

This is the disassembly at the point where the method gets called (I'm compiling with `-O0`): (comments by me, with what i *think* is going on)

```
=> 0x001ee394 <+576>:   ldr r0, [r11, #-24] ; 0xffffffe8                    "Load address of p_msg into r0"
   0x001ee398 <+580>:   bl  0x1f0658 <LLRP::CREADER_EVENT_NOTIFICATION::getReaderEventNotificationData()> "call getReaderEventNotificationData"
   0x001ee39c <+584>:   str r0, [r11, #-28] ; 0xffffffe4                    "store r0 on the stack at sp-28"
   0x001ee3a0 <+588>:   ldr r3, [r11, #-28] ; 0xffffffe4                    "load sp-28 into r3"
   0x001ee3a4 <+592>:   cmp r3, #0                                          "check if rd is NULL"
```

Here is the c++ code and disassembly of the method that gets called (`p_msg->getReaderEventNotificationData()`):

```cpp
inline CReaderEventNotificationData *
getReaderEventNotificationData (void)
{
    return m_pReaderEventNotificationData;
}
```

```
   0x001f0658 <+0>:     push    {r11}       ; (str r11, [sp, #-4]!) "save r11"
   0x001f065c <+4>:     add r11, sp, #0                             "save sp in r11"
   0x001f0660 <+8>:     sub sp, sp, #12                             "decrement sp by 12"
   0x001f0664 <+12>:    str r0, [r11, #-8]                          "store r0 on the stack at sp-8"
=> 0x001f0668 <+16>:    ldr r3, [r11, #-8]                          "load sp-8 into r3"
   0x001f066c <+20>:    ldr r3, [r3, #24]                           "load r3+24 into r3 THIS IS WRONG!"
                                                                    "m_pReaderEventNotificationData is at offset 28 not 24"
   0x001f0670 <+24>:    mov r0, r3                                  "move r3 into r0 as the return value"
   0x001f0674 <+28>:    add sp, r11, #0                             "restore sp"
   0x001f0678 <+32>:    pop {r11}       ; (ldr r11, [sp], #4)       "restore r11"
   0x001f067c <+36>:    bx  lr                                      "return"
```

If i take a look at the momory at the address `p_msg`, this is what it looks like:

```
0x69405de8: 0x002bcbf8  0x002b8774  0x00000000  0x69408200
0x69405df8: 0x69408200  0x5c5a5b1a  0x00000000  0x6940ed90
0x69405e08: 0x00000028  0x0000012d  0x694035f0  0x694007c8
```

So at offset `24`, it's actually `0x00000000` and that's what returned by the method. But The correct value that should be returned is actually at offset `28` (`0x6940ed90`)

Is this a compiler problem? Or some 64 bit thing?

This is the compiler version btw: `gcc version 8.3.0 (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1)`

Comment: It's very hard to say for sure what's happening. Please make a [mre] so that we can try it out.

Comment: You need to step over that line of code for the assignment to execute.

Comment: Bizarre.  My first bet is that there is undefined behavior somewhere.  If not that, then I'd check to make sure your compiler is up to date and the latest version.

Comment: Are you positive that the `0x6920ae10` is actually the return value from that function and not the address of the function itself? It isn't clear from the video.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I don't really know how to replicate the problem, it just happens in that one instance here.. But repeatably, every time i run the code, regardless of whether it's running in the debugger or not. But I'll try to isolate it a bit more to get a smaller example.

Comment: @Eljay The compiler is gcc version 8.3.0. I just updated the raspbian packages and didn't receive a gcc update so i think that's the most recent version available for this distribution. I'll try to upgrade the LLRP/LTK library, maybe there is a newer version of that available.

Comment: @h0r53 yep i'm pretty sure.. You can also see the value when i hover over the p_msg_ren variable in the outer code, and it's the value of the m_pReaderEventNotificationData member that is returned by the method.

Comment: Perhaps this is related to a timing issue, such as a race condition. From what you've illustrated it does look like the value should be properly assigned. However, from the time of the breakpoint being hit it's possible the original value updated from NULL to `0x6920ae10`, which could have led to the NULL assignment to `p_msg_ren_d`. It's impossible to tell without additional context, but I'd start by breaking before the assignment and stepping through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What could cause this problem?

The most likely cause is that you've compiled your code with optimization, and are getting confused. Does the program proceed to report `invalid response from reader`, or does it actually continue to line 181.

If the latter, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8067626/50617).

If the program really does go to execute line 179, then it is likely that your compiler has miscompiled your program (you'll need to disassemble the code to be sure).

In that case, trying different compiler versions, disabling optimizations for a particular function or file, changing optimization levels, etc. etc. may let you work around the compiler bug.

**Update:**

> The program does report the invalid response from reader, so it is actually called. I spent all afternoon investigating this again and at this point i believe it's a compiler error. In the disassembly i can see that it tries to load the value of `m_pReaderEventNotificationData`
> from the object-address+24 (`ldr r3, [r3, #24]`) but if i view the memory, at this offset is actually 0x000000. The real value that it should return is at offset #28 instead of #24.

This is actually a very common problem, *usually* stemming from an ODR violation or an incomplete rebuilt.

Suppose you have two object files: `foo.o` and `bar.o`, and also define

```
const int NUM_X = 6;
struct Bar {
  int m_x[NUM_X];
  void *m_p;
  void *Fn() { return m_p;}
};
```

Given above, `Fn()` will return `*(this + 24)`, and this offset will be compiled into both object files.

Now you change `NUM_X` from 6 to 7, and rebuild `foo.o` but *not* `bar.o`. `Fn` inside `bar.o` will *still* return `*(this +24)`, but it *should* return `*(this + 28)` (assuming 32-bit binary).

Similar behavior could happen if `struct Bar` is defined differently in `foo.cc` and `bar.cc` (ODR violation).

**Update 2:**

> I deleted all traces of the library from the disk and recompiled the .a file and reinstalled the library and the headers. I also tried to recompile the program when the lib was not present and got a linker error so it's definitely not using another version of the lib that i don't know about... I also deleted the complete build of the program and fully recompiled it... But it's still the same behavior..

You should verify that both files involved see the *same* definition of `CREADER_EVENT_NOTIFICATION`. Best to capture preprocessed files and compare the definition there (this is what the compiler *actually* sees). Be sure to use the *exact* compilation commands you used to build the library and the application.

One sneaky way ODR violations can creep in is if the `#define`s in effect when building the library and the application are different. For example, consider this code:

```
#ifdef NUM_XX
const int NUM_X = NUM_XX;
#else
const int NUM_X = 6;
#endif

struct Bar {
  int m_x[NUM_X];
  void *m_p;
  void *Fn() { return m_p;}
};
```

Now compile `foo.cc` with `-DNUM_XX=7` and `bar.cc` without it, and you've got an ODR violation.

Comment: The program does report the `invalid response from reader`, so it is actually called. I spent all afternoon investigating this again and at this point i believe it's a compiler error. In the disassembly i can see that it tries to load the value of `m_pReaderEventNotificationData` from the object-address+24 (`ldr r3, [r3, #24]`) but if i view the memory, at this offset is actually 0x000000. The real value that it should return is at offset #28 instead of #24. Can this be some x86/x64 mismatch problem?

Comment: I updated the question with the disassembly and memory view now.

Comment: @Spike101 I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update.. I deleted all traces of the library from the disk and recompiled the .a file and reinstalled the library and the headers. I also tried to recompile the program when the lib was not present and got a linker error so it's definitely not using another version of the lib that i don't know about... I also deleted the complete build of the program and fully recompiled it... But it's still the same behavior... I did not yet try changing the optimization level. I'll try that tomorrow, maybe it help, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Spike101 A second update.

Comment: Thanks again for the tips. I got it working now. The library was using a `std::list` and i think the library and the program hat a disagreement about what a `std::list` is... For some reason, my program had the compiler option `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` enabled. After removing it it works now.

Comment: @Spike101 Sneaky indeed! Glad you found it.