# Results Differ When Compiling with Debug Flags

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

Code that I am working on is producing incorrect results when compiled without debug flags (g++ main.cpp dbscan.cpp), but produces correct results when debug flags are used (g++ -g main.cpp dbscan.cpp)

The code, described below, has been pared down for the sake of this question.

dbscan.h contains a struct Point and a class constructor DBSCAN:

```
typedef struct Point_{
    float x, y;  // X, Y position
    int clusterID;  // clustered ID
}Point;
```

```
DBSCAN(vector<Point> points){
    m_points = points;
    m_pointSize = points.size();
}
```

In main.cpp, I create a vector of Points and then pass it to the constructor, and run a class function that prints the vector.

```
vector<Point> points;
points.resize(5);

for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    points[i].x = i;
    points[i].y = i;
    points[i].clusterID = -1;
}

// constructor
DBSCAN ds(points);
ds.run();
```

Note that ClusterID for each Point should be -1.

Right now, all the run() function does is print the vector.

```
int DBSCAN::run()
{
    cout<<"In Run"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<m_points.size();i++)
    {
        cout<<"X: "<< m_points[i].x <<" Y: "<< m_points[i].y << " ClusterID: "<< m_points[i].clusterID<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In the run() function is where the differences occur. If I compile WITHOUT debug, clusterID prints a value that is not -1, and therefore incorrect.

Non-debug compiled output

```
X: 0 Y: 0 ClusterID: 1065353216
X: 1 Y: 1 ClusterID: 1073741824
X: 2 Y: 2 ClusterID: 1077936128
X: 3 Y: 3 ClusterID: 1082130432
X: 4 Y: 4 ClusterID: 0
```

When I tried to use gdb to debug, I noticed that it was producing the right values, whether I run it with gdb or just by itself as ./a.out

```
X: 0 Y: 0 ClusterID: -1
X: 1 Y: 1 ClusterID: -1
X: 2 Y: 2 ClusterID: -1
X: 3 Y: 3 ClusterID: -1
X: 4 Y: 4 ClusterID: -1
```

Any ideas on why:
1.) The ClusterID would change between the initial setting in the constructor and then in run()?
2.) Why compiling with debug flags (-g) would fix it?

Note that I had tried putting test output statements both within the constructor and right before run() to see what the ClusterIDs were, and they were the appropriate value of -1. It's only within run() that the values become incorrect.

EDIT:
Thanks to everyone informing me that I should have posted a minimal reproducible example. I have done as suggested here: http://cpp.sh/5cakb

Frustratingly, the error is not occurring there, and only when I have the code separated between multiple files (dbscan.cpp, dbscan.h, and main.cpp). I think I have some aspects to investigate (ensuring deep copying of the vector is being done in the constructor), so I'll check that out. For completeness, I'm going to post the individual files here as well for a full picture of how the code is split on my system. I know it won't be runnable on the webpage, but just wanted to give the full picture.

- dbscan.h: http://cpp.sh/93w3g
- dbscan.cpp: http://cpp.sh/3wsea
- main.cpp: http://cpp.sh/5u7fn

Comment: Very likely you have _undefined behavior_, that's a typical symptom. Provide a [mcve] as it's required here for such questions please.

Comment: Also, the use of old-school C-syntax makes my ears wriggle. I have to wonder what is going on that you haven't shown us. You're actually typedef-ing your struct? Is everything being compiled as C++? Should you have an `extern "C"` wrapping an include file?

Comment: TO be clear -- your pared-down version still exhibits this behavior between debug and non debug flag versions?

Comment: If history has taught us anything, the likelihood of reading what a [mcve] really is will be unlikely, so let me sum it up for you. If we can take the code in your question, and *only* the code in your question, copy/paste, compile, run, provide any input needed (which is also provided verbatim in your question), and *then* the same problem you're trying to solve surfaces, *then* we can probably help you. Otherwise we're left guessing about what we don't see. Guesses aren't answers; they're guesses. So *please*, post a [mcve].

Comment: Off-topic, but introducing extraneous variables such as `m_pointSize` to denote the number of entries in the vector is not only unnecessary, it is error-prone.  The vector `size()` member function always is correct, so use it only.  Having extraneous and unnecessary variables like that just increases your chances of bugs to happen.  What if the vector is resized, and your `m_pointSize` is not updated?

Comment: Here's the deal -- take [this code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c353a9103efa4eda), and add to it until you see the error that you're claiming happens.  Or even do this:  start fresh with that code at the link, and add *slowly* the code in your existing program to it (compiling, running, etc.).  If in that process, you see the breakage you're claiming, post *that* code.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thanks for the suggestion, I'll go through and reformat the question to make it minimally reproducible when I am able to later on.

Comment: @JosephLarson I'll produce a minimally reproducible example as others had suggested, but there is nothing else going on. All other code sections had been commented out, and the pieces shown above are all that remains. In regards to the syntax, this code originated from a 3D DBSCAN library (https://github.com/james-yoo/DBSCAN) that I'm trying to modify for a 2D use case.

Comment: @JohnFilleau Yup, the pared down code you see above is what I am compiling and running that is getting different results. I'll produce modify the post with a minimal reproducible example to make it more clear.

Comment: @WhozCraig Roger that. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for the suggestion. I'll take note and change things on my end accordingly.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for putting that together. This was my first post here, but I realize now my question/code wasn't formatted in a way very conducive to getting feedback. I'll see I can produce to incorrect results I'm seeing off of what you linked.

Comment: @TheEternalCowboy It still makes me feel suspicious, the use of some C syntax like typedefing the struct. This clearly isn't all the code, so I still wonder if you're mixing C and C++ without realizing it.

Comment: @JosephLarson Thanks for looping back around on this. I'm still trying to wrap my head around the error. At this point, with the http://cpp.sh links I shared, it IS all the code. I did some more digging and starting printing out memory addresses instead of values, and found that the when I view the ClusterID in run(), it's looking at the address 4 bytes past where it should. Compiling with -g or -O fixes this.

I'm currently firing up another Ubuntu VM to see if it's my system or what. Either way,  I'm completely perplexed why it would look at the wrong address here.

Comment: @TheEternalCowboy This clearly isn't all the code as we don't see the .h file for DBSCAN or where you are #including it. We don't see most of the code for DBSCAN. And what C++ programmer typedefs a struct? That's a C-ism. Are you linking against a library or compiling everything yourself? Are you compiling everything with G++ or is some with GCC? Is there a shared library involved, and you don't even know how it was compiled?

Comment: @JosephLarson I figured it out! To go into detail, I have a folder that I had thought contained only the 3  files from above, and was compiling with g++. The folder structure was just ~/temp, with dbscan.h/.cpp and main.cpp. I compiled with "g++ main.cpp dbscan.cpp". The issue I just discovered was that I must have used gcc to compile before, which left a ".gch" file. That ".gch" file was still holding header info from the original files I was modifying that had x, y, AND z in the struct, which was messing up the memory addresses rather than throwing an error. Deleting that fixed things.

Comment: @JosephLarson Overall, I appreciate the help and kindness on my first Stack Overflow usage. I've definitely learned some things on how to better prepare questions here for everyone's benefit, and will do so in the future.

Comment: @TheEternalCowboy -- Precompiled headers will sometimes make you go crazy trying to figure out issues like these -- it's the same issue with the Visual C++ compiler.  Maybe some day, compiler tools will become advanced enough to, at the very least, warn that your changes may require cleaning of the precompiled header (if this doesn't exist already).

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas on why: 1.) The ClusterID would change between the initial setting in the constructor and then in run()?

Most likely reason: your program exercises undefined behavior.

Without [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), we can't tell where or how it happens, but you may get some clues by building your code with `-Wall -Wextra` (do pay attention to any compiler warnings produced), or by building with `-fsanitize=address` and running the program. If you can build your code with `clang`, using `-fsanitize=undefined` is also a good choice.

> 2.) Why compiling with debug flags (-g) would fix it?

*Just* adding `-g` rarely changes program behaviour. Most likely you are adding `-g` *and* removing optimization flags (`-O`, `-O2` or similar).

If that is the case, note that:

1. removing optimization *very often* hides bugs and
2. you *can* build with `-g -O2` and debug resulting code, though doing so presents its own [challenges](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8067626/50617).

Comment: Thanks for the response! I just discovered the issue was that I had a lingering ".gch" file, which was a precompiled header file from a past version of dbscan.h that had a third point Z, in addition to X and Y. Rather than causing an error, it just displaced the memory addresses I was referencing. Compiling with -g and -O fixed the issue, I'm guessing because it didn't look at the precompiled header? In any case, deleting the gch file allowed the regular compiles to function.